# Access query to find who didn't test over a range of dates

Tags: ms-access

I am hoping someone can help me out with a query that may not be possible in Access.

I have a table with all employees and a query that shows everyone that has tested over an 18 month or so period and growing.  
I am trying to figure out how I can do a query in access that will show what employees have not tested on individual dates within a range of dates.  For example, if I create a query of the dates 10/1/17 – 10/14/17 then the result I am hoping for is that Jim did not test on 10/1 and 10/5 and Joe didn't test on 10/12.

It works great for a single date as it compares only the results from a single date query against the employee table and whoever is not in both did not test, but only for that date.

This is the SQL view of the single day “did not test” query:

```
SELECT ESD_EMP_BADGE.LAST_NAME, ESD_EMP_BADGE.FIRST_NAME, ESD_EMP_BADGE.EMPID, ESD_EMP_BADGE.DEPT
FROM ESD_EMP_BADGE LEFT JOIN Yesterday ON ESD_EMP_BADGE.[EMPID] = Yesterday.[EMPID] 
WHERE (((ESD_EMP_BADGE.DEPT) Not Like "EXE") AND ((Yesterday.EMPID) Is Null));
```

For a range, I cannot do it the same way as the single date query because if that person tested at some time during the range of the query a single test in that range will make it seem like that person tested for all dates.
Is there a way that each date can be considered separately within a single query?
There is only one field that is guaranteed to be unique in the employee table that is also in the test records “EMPID”. There is no date field in the employee table.   
I hope this is clear enough of an explanation. I think I might be reaching beyond what Access can do.

Comment: Can you provide same sample data of the employee table, what the "query that shows everyone that has tested" produces and what the result data would look like? And while you are at it, can you please format the SQL code by prepending 4 spaces? That will create a neat block of code.

Comment: What would be the best way to get the sample data posted?  Simple text or should I export the data to excel or something?  Keep in mind there are a few fields in the main query that are not needed in the query I am trying to create results.

Comment: What is necessary for an example should easily fit in as text; just edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are looking for - you will first need a dataset of all possible combinations of employees and test dates. This dataset can be generated with a query that includes employees and tests taken tables without a join clause. This is a Cartesian relationship of records - every record in each table joins with each record in the other table.
`SELECT Employees.EmpID, EmpTests.TestDate FROM Employees, EmpTests;`

Then join that query back to the testing table.

```
SELECT Query1.EmpID, Query1.TestDate, EmpTests.TestDate
FROM EmpTests RIGHT JOIN Query1 ON (EmpTests.TestDate = Query1.TestDate) AND (EmpTests.EmpID = Query1.EmpID)
WHERE (((Query1.TestDate) Between [start date] And [end date]) AND ((EmpTests.TestDate) Is Null));
```